# Easy and quick loop to extract values from another row in R, based on condition?

Tags: r, dataframe, dataset, panel, panel-data

I am working with a panel dataset where individual identifiers are not available. What I have, instead, is an identifier for households fixed across waves (variable *nquest*), an identifier for individuals within each household changing across waves (variable *nord*) and an identifier for individuals referring to the value of the variable *nord* in the previous wave (variable *nordp*). So, a simplified dataframe would look like this:

| row | Year | nquest | nord | nordp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2010 | 1 | 1 | NA |
| 2 | 2012 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2012 | 1 | 2 | NA |
| 4 | 2012 | 1 | 3 | NA |
| 5 | 2014 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 6 | 2014 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 7 | 2010 | 2 | 1 | NA |
| 8 | 2010 | 2 | 2 | NA |
| 9 | 2012 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 10 | 2012 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 11 | 2012 | 2 | 3 | NA |

In this example, rows 1, 2, and 5 refer to the same individual; as well as 4 and 6, 7 and 9, and 8 and 10 (again, *nordp* refers to *nord* in the previous wave, whereas *nquest* is fixed).

Is there a quick way to come up with a variable identifying the same individual across waves? I've tried with for loops creating complicated labels and extracting characters across waves but it takes ages (the dataset is large, but still) and I'm sure there is an easier way, with *dplyr* or something. Differently from other solutions I've found on the website, I would need to do that for every single observation - so without specifying values for *nord* or *nordp* or *nquest*.

Thank you!

EDIT: Here an example of how my data look like, where I added the last column "id" based on my need. In particular what matters is to recognize that, for instance, the individual in *year* 2016 from *nquest* 2 with *nord* 2 is the same that in *year* 2014 was identified with *nord* 3 (because *nordp* in *year* 2016 = 3), who is also the same that in *year* 2012 and 2010 was identified with *nord* 2 (because *nordp* in year* 2014 and 2012 = 2).

```
test<-data.frame(year=c("2010","2012","2012","2012","2014","2014","2010"
,"2010","2012","2012","2012","2012","2014","2014","2014","2016","2016"),
nquest=c("1","1","1","1","1","1","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2"
,"2"),nord=c("1","1","2","3","1","2","1","2","1","2","3","4","1","2","3"
,"1","2"),nordp=c("NA","1","NA","NA","1","3","NA","NA","1","2","NA","NA"
,"NA","1","2","1","3"),id=c("1","1","2","3","1","3","4","5","4","5","6",
"7","8","8","5","8","5"))

   year  nquest nord  nordp
   <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr>
 1 2010  1      1     NA   
 2 2012  1      1     1    
 3 2012  1      2     NA   
 4 2012  1      3     NA   
 5 2014  1      1     1    
 6 2014  1      2     3    
 7 2010  2      1     NA   
 8 2010  2      2     NA   
 9 2012  2      1     1    
10 2012  2      2     2    
11 2012  2      3     NA   
12 2012  2      4     NA   
13 2014  2      1     NA   
14 2014  2      2     1    
15 2014  2      3     2    
16 2016  2      1     1    
17 2016  2      2     3
```

Comment: Hi @akrun, 

Ideally I would have an extra column with values `1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3`.

It could take a different form (I was thinking of a string combining *nquest* with the first *nord* available): what matters is that it makes me distinguish across individuals.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following `dplyr` approach, which uses `mutate` to make a new `id` column, and `case_when` to implement the logic.

As a best practice (coming from someone who makes a lot of identifiers in their data), instead of making the IDs sequential it may be better to concatenate the family id (`nquest`) with the individual family member ID. This would allow the simultaneous identification of both the family and the individual. For convenience purposes, it is also better to make IDs alphanumeric - so the below outputs an ID "Kx-x" where the first integer is the family ID and the second is the individual ID. The letter K is arbitrary.

```
library(dplyr)

new_df <- df %>%
  group_by(nquest) %>%
  mutate(id = case_when(
    nord == 1 | nordp == 1 ~ 1,
    is.na(nordp) ~ as.numeric(nord),
    TRUE ~ as.numeric(nordp)
  ),
  id = paste0("K",nquest,"-" id))
```

Output:

```
#      row  Year nquest  nord nordp id   
#    <int> <int>  <int> <int> <int> <chr>
#  1     1  2010      1     1    NA K1-1 
#  2     2  2012      1     1     1 K1-1 
#  3     3  2012      1     2    NA K1-2 
#  4     4  2012      1     3    NA K1-3 
#  5     5  2014      1     1     1 K1-1 
#  6     6  2014      1     2     3 K1-3 
#  7     7  2010      2     1    NA K2-1 
#  8     8  2010      2     2    NA K2-2 
#  9     9  2012      2     1     1 K2-1 
# 10    10  2012      2     2     2 K2-2 
# 11    11  2012      2     3    NA K2-3
```

Data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "row    Year    nquest  nord    nordp
1   2010    1   1   NA
2   2012    1   1   1
3   2012    1   2   NA
4   2012    1   3   NA
5   2014    1   1   1
6   2014    1   2   3
7   2010    2   1   NA
8   2010    2   2   NA
9   2012    2   1   1
10  2012    2   2   2
11  2012    2   3   NA", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @jpsmith. Apologies for not making this clear earlier, but in my examples I have several *nquest* (i.e., housholds). So this association should be conditional on *nord* and *nordp* belonging to the same *nquest*.
Any idea on how I could implement this condition too? Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you @jpsmith, I have just seen now the update. I will try this solution shortly and will let you know if it works - thanks a ton!

Comment: @a_jazz_man See the edit I just made - I took a bit of liberty in your question but hopefully it will help. Let me know if this works for you or else I can re-edit

Comment: I perfectly agree with the identifier name. I've tried the updated code, maybe I got something wrong but there seems to be one remaining issue: in your example, is it possible that it works because *nord* doesn't change for those who have to be linked across more than two waves? When I apply it, the *id* variable correctly reports the previous *nord*, but it's not able to match this previous *nord* with the corresponding *nordp* (which again refers to the same individual in the previous wave).

Comment: Hmmm... could you edit your question to share your data using `dput(your_data)` or a sample of it with `dput(head(your_data, 25))`? This might allow me to tailor it to your specific needs since it works with the dummy data. Hopefully we can find a solution!

Comment: Hi @jpsmith, just added a clearer example. Let me know if it is unclear and thanks for bearing with me

Comment: Hi @jpsmith, I think I found a solution that works in base R. If you have any idea of how to make it faster I'd be very grateful (at the moment it takes more than two hours). Anyway, thanks for your help yesterday!